# Get X first elements out of list

Tags: haskell

Let’s consider 2 lists: `["a","b","c"]` and `["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`

I want to check if the first list is the beginning of the other list
I thought I could use:

```
["a","b","c"] == head (splitAt (length ["a","b","c"]) ["a","b","c","d","e","f"])
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there another way to get the first the 3 first elements out of a list in a new list?

Comment: `take 3 ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` ? You should get to know Prelude http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html and use Hoogle http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/. For example, your function could be found jus by giving Hoogle the types: `[a] -> [a]` (i.e. you ask Hoogle "give me functions that take a list of items and return a list of items") http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D

Comment: your code would work if you just used `fst` instead of `head`. `fst` takes first element of a pair, `head` takes head element of a non-empty list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using `take`, you could use `zipWith` to avoid traversing the lists twice.  When you call `length`, you first have to traverse the shorter list, then you take that many values from the longer list, then you traverse the lists, comparing element by element.  What would make more sense is to traverse both lists as the same time, stopping your comparison when the shorter one is expired.  `zipWith` provides exactly this functionality:

```
-- Definitions for `and` and `zipWith` in `Prelude`
--
-- and :: [Bool] -> Bool
-- and [] = True
-- and (x:xs) = x && and xs
--
-- zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
-- zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
-- zipWith _ _      _      = []

sameStartingElements :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
sameStartingElements xs ys = and $ zipWith (==) xs ys
```

Thanks to laziness, this definition will only traverse both lists once, and it stops as soon as one of them runs out of elements.  This will be somewhat more efficient, and it avoids having to know the length of either list.

Answer (score 5):

The function you're looking for is `take`. See [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:take).

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you can improve your answer by 1) Adding a link to the documentation 2) add an example of its usage 3) Mention where the OP can find the most often used functions (i.e. `Prelude`, and maybe mention `Data.List`) 4) How he can search for existing functions (i.e. Hoogle).

Comment: Great, I got it working now. Thanks alot for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to check if the first list is the beginning of the other list.

You can use [`isPrefixOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) from the Data.List module.